# how to pass property from parent component to child component via slot

Tags: vuejs3

I have a component that determines whether an area becomes visible when scrolling. How can I pass a variable set in the parent component to the child.

this is what it looks like in a simple application

```
<ScrollSectionVideo>
     <VideoComponent></VideoComponent>
</ScrollSectionVideo>
```

the ScrollSectionVideo Componente is a ScrollObserver, which on the one hand handles the display and on the other hand passes on a play property to the videocomponent

```
<template v-slot="play">
     <div class="scrollSectionOff" :class="{ scrollSection: isVisible}" ref="scrollRef" >
         {{ play }}
         <slot :play="play"></slot>
     </div>
</template>
```

the video components looks as follows.

```
<template>
     <div class="video grid">
         {{ props }}
       <video src="/video/projektor_v3.mp4" ref="videoRef" volume="0" loop="1"></video>
     </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watch, onMounted} from 'vue';

export default {
     props: {
          play: {
             type: Boolean,
             required: false,
             default: false
         }
     },

     setup(props) {
         const videoRef = ref(null)
         console.log(props)

         watch(() => props.play, (first, second) => {
             console.log( "watch props.play", first, second);
             if (props.play==true){
                     videoRef.value.play();
             } else {
                 videoRef.value.pause();
             }
             // setTimeout (()=> {
             // videoToggle.value = true;
             // }, 300);
         });


         return {
             props,
             videoRef
         }
        
     },
}
</script>
```

the output of the two components confuses me.
true {{ play }} from parent
{ "play": { "play": true } } // {{ props }} from videochild.

why is it nested? how do i get a simple {play: true}?